# How to remove a specific email field autofill in Chrome desktop browser

Tags: google-chrome, auto-form-fill

When I click on an email form-field I get autofill options. How do I remove one specific email from that list, which I no longer use?

I use Chrome browser on Mac OS and I can't seem to find this setting while searching 'autofill' in settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On the email field, use the <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys to select the email address from the list.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to remove the email address.

Comment: Shift+Del worked, thank you!